# Multi parameters Dictionary (collection list) Like: [[String: Any]] to Alamofire Parameters

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, alamofire, swift5

Hi i am trying to give to alamofire parameters called "Dict" that are in dictionary...dictionary can contain 3 or X items. I am trying to use FOR cycle to ad dictionary to another one set of items, but...it only shows the last one...that seems it override the previous one. I tried everything I know...Even try to use SwiftyJSON framework....but alamofire only take pure dictionary type.

```
    var Dict = [[String: Any]]()
    
    Dict.removeAll()
    
    for (index, value) in _SurveySubmitModel.enumerated() {
        print("Item \(index + 1): \(value)")
        
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "ID": value.ID,
            "SurveyID": value.SurveyID,
            "QuestionID": value.QuestionID,
            "FilledBy": value.FilledBy,
            "Response": value.Response
        ]
        
        Dict.append(parameters)
        
    }
    
    print("Dict = \(Dict)")
```

well I need something like this

```
 [{
  "ID": 0,
  "SurveyID": 25,
  "QuestionID": 28,
  "FilledBy": 7335,
  "Response": "1In the two weeks before you felt sick, did you:"
 },
 {
  "ID": 0,
  "SurveyID": 25,
  "QuestionID": 28,
  "FilledBy": 7335,
  "Response": "1In the two weeks before you felt sick, did you:"
 }
 ]
```

Comment: What data type is _SurveySubmitModel?

Comment: Hi @Prakash thanks for your reply, i use this model like:

struct SurveySubmitModel: Codable {
    var ID = Int()
    var SurveyID = Int()
    var QuestionID = Int()
    var FilledBy = Int()
    var Response = String()
}

Comment: then one element will be in _SurveySubmitModel? It is not array or collection.  Instead of that you can use var surveryList = [SurveySubmitModel] and save all your data into it.

Comment: yes i use same like that you sent: var _SurveySubmitModel = [SurveySubmitModel]()

and i add data like:

_SurveySubmitModel.append(SurveySubmitModel(ID: 0, SurveyID: 25, QuestionID: 28, FilledBy: 7335, Response: "1In the two weeks before you felt sick, did you:"))

but Alamofire did not support this. i think i miss some step can you tell me if you got my point?

Comment: Can you share the code that collecting all data in your collection? So that i can help

Comment: - here is my list: 
_SurveySubmitModel.append(SurveySubmitModel(ID: 0, SurveyID: 25, QuestionID: 28, FilledBy: 7335, Response: "1In the two weeks before you felt sick, did you:"))

Comment: - here is my dictionary where I get all data:
var Dict = [[String: Any]]()
        for (index, value) in _SurveySubmitModel.enumerated() {
            let parameters: [String: Any] = [
                "ID": value.ID,
                "SurveyID": value.SurveyID,
                "QuestionID": value.QuestionID,
                "FilledBy": value.FilledBy,
                "Response": value.Response
            ]
            Dict.append(parameters)
        }

Comment: - here is alamofire method
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: Dict, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers
            ).validate().responseJSON
            { response in
                
                completion(response)
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, I have modified `[String: Any]` to `NSDictionary`. Also Changed `for` loop.

```
var _SurveySubmitModel = [SurveySubmitModel]()

_SurveySubmitModel.append(SurveySubmitModel(ID: 0, SurveyID: 25, QuestionID: 28, FilledBy: 7335, Response: "1In the two weeks before you felt sick, did you:"))
_SurveySubmitModel.append(SurveySubmitModel(ID: 0, SurveyID: 25, QuestionID: 28, FilledBy: 7335, Response: "1In the two weeks before you felt sick, did you:"))
        
for survey in _SurveySubmitModel {
    
    let parameters: NSDictionary = [
        "ID": survey.ID,
        "SurveyID": survey.SurveyID,
        "QuestionID": survey.QuestionID,
        "FilledBy": survey.FilledBy,
        "Response": survey.Response
    ]
    
    Dict.append(parameters)
    
}
print("Dict == ", Dict)
```

Output is

```
Dict ==  [{
    FilledBy = 7335;
    ID = 0;
    QuestionID = 28;
    Response = "1In the two weeks before you felt sick, did you:";
    SurveyID = 25;
}, {
    FilledBy = 7335;
    ID = 0;
    QuestionID = 28;
    Response = "1In the two weeks before you felt sick, did you:";
    SurveyID = 25;
}]
```

Try below function to web service call

```
func postValues(requestParams: [[String: AnyObject]], urlString: String) {

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestParams, options: [])

    AF.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
          //  print(response.result.value)
            break
        case .failure:
            print(response.error)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Prakash , this solution is working but my question is, how I can pass the final Dict in Alamofire as a parameter? because Alamofire only accept [String: Any] not [[String: Any]]

here is my code where I can put "Dict"

ClientApi.objGlobalMethod.ServiceMethod(url: surveySubmitApi(sitename: SiteId), method: "POST", parameters: Dict ) { (response) in
            
            print("response = \(response)")

Comment: If it's a POST method, params should go in body, so just do the JSON parsing (If it's JSON) using JSONSerilzaition and put it yourself. Look for all "Alamofire + Array + Parameter", you'll see answers.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Prakash it's working now, You save my day.